# Handling of special cases of punctuation when creating tokens with regex

Tags: python, regex

I managed to break up a sentence on the basis of the present punctuation. For instance:

```
import re
sentence = 'i was born in germany (near Frankfurt, in the center of the country) but i live in france. what about you? i know you have a similar story.'
print(list(filter(None, re.split('[!(),.:;?]+', sentence))))
```

which returns

```
['i was born in germany ', 'near Frankfurt', ' in the center of the country', ' but i live in france', ' what about you', ' i know you have a similar story']
```

Now I don't know how to handle some special cases of punctuation for example:

```
sentence_1 = 'abc.io is a company that employs 10,000 people, half of them in greece.'
```

with my method I get:

```
['abc', 'io is a company that employs 10', '000 people', ' half of them in greece']
```

but I would like to obtain:

```
['abc.io is a company that employs 10,000 people', ' half of them in greece']
```

how can I handle this situation (and similar situations too)?

Comment: So, you want to avoid splitting on a dot between word chars and a comma between two digits?

Comment: Have a look: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/07/how-get-started-nlp-6-unique-ways-perform-tokenization/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, I would like to avoid splitting on a dot or a comma between elements (words and numbers) (would this cause problems with the periods at the end of the sentence?)

Comment: No, there should be no problem with those chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split matching on the punctuation chars except for the dot and comma, or match the dot and comma followed by a whitespace boundary.

```
[!():;?]|[.,](?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tFWJje/1)

Then you can filter the result for empty entries.

```
import re

strings = [
    "i was born in germany (near Frankfurt, in the center of the country) but i live in france. what about you? i know you have a similar story.",
    "abc.io is a company that employs 10,000 people, half of them in greece."
]

pattern = "[!():;?]|[.,](?!\S)"

for s in strings:
    print([res for res in re.split(pattern, s) if res])
```

Output

```
['i was born in germany ', 'near Frankfurt', ' in the center of the country', ' but i live in france', ' what about you', ' i know you have a similar story']
['abc.io is a company that employs 10,000 people', ' half of them in greece']
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try splitting on `[!(),.:;?]+(?!\S)`:

```py
sentence_1 = 'abc.io is a company that employs 10,000 people, half of them in greece.'
matches = re.split(r'[!(),.:;?]+(?!\S)', sentence_1)
matches = [x for x in matches if x != '']
print(matches)

# ['abc.io is a company that employs 10,000 people', ' half of them in greece']
```

This answer assumes that a punctuation split should only occur when punctuation is followed by whitespace or the end of the input.  We filter off empty string matches which might arise.

Comment: It keeps the dot at the end of the second token. Is it possible not to consider it through regex or should I remove it at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
re.split(r'(?:,(?!(?<=\d.)\d)|(?!\b\.\b)\.|[!():;?])+', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WTwBhj/1). It matches

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `,(?!(?<=\d.)\d)`  - a comma not between digits
  - `|` - or
  - `(?!\b\.\b)\.` - a dot that is not enclosed with word chars
  - `|` - or
  - `[!():;?]` - a char from the set
- `)+` - end of the group, one or more times

Comment: With `print(re.split('(?:,(?!(?<=\d.)\d)|(?!\b\.\b)\.|[!():;?])+', sentence_1))` I get `['abc', 'io is a company that employs 10,000 people', ' half of them in greece', '']`

Comment: @LJG You must use a raw string literal. I updated the answer.

Comment: I don't think it includes all cases: if the sentence is `abc.io is a (strange) company that employs 10,000 people, half of them in greece.` then the result is `['abc.io is a (strange', ' company that employs 10,000 people', ' half of them in greece']` instead of `['abc.io is a ', 'strange', ' company that employs 10,000 people', ' half of them in greece']`

Answer (score 0):

You could demand a space after a special character:

```
print(list(filter(None, re.split('[!(),.:;?]\s+', sentence_1))))
```

which gives the desired result

Comment: It keeps the final dot. Is it possible not to consider it through regex or should I remove it at the beginning?